# Angular using ng-model with expression in directive template

Tags: angularjs

I want to use the ng-model attribute in a custom element. The problem is, that I need to set the ng-model with an expression:

```
ng-model="{{anyVariable}}"
```

The problem is, that I always get an error as soon I add the expression to the ng-model attribute in my template:

```
Error: Syntax Error: Token 'x.name' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{x.name}}] starting at [x.name}}].
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at throwError (http://localhost:9000/public/javascripts/angular.js:5999:11)
    at consume (http://localhost:9000/public/javascripts/angular.js:6037:7)
    at object (http://localhost:9000/public/javascripts/angular.js:6327:9)
    at primary (http://localhost:9000/public/javascripts/angular.js:6211:17)
    at unary (http://localhost:9000/public/javascripts/angular.js:6198:14)
    at multiplicative (http://localhost:9000/public/javascripts/angular.js:6181:16)
    at additive (http://localhost:9000/public/javascripts/angular.js:6172:16)
    at relational (http://localhost:9000/public/javascripts/angular.js:6163:16)
    at equality (http://localhost:9000/public/javascripts/angular.js:6154:16)
```

The code used:

```
function addFormFieldDirective(elementName, template) {
    app.directive(elementName, function() {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {},
            replace: true,
                              // adds some extra layout
            template: buildFormTemplate(template),
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
                scope.x = attrs;
            }
         };
    });
}
addFormFieldDirective("textfield", '<input id="{{x.id}}" ng-model="{{x.name}}" type="text" name="{{x.name}}" value="{{x.value}}" />');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to pass an expression to `ng-model` within the directive template.

Following solution creates an isolated model within the directive and directive `controller` dynamically creates the property name in main controller model object and watches the isolated model to pass updates to main model:

```
app.directive("textfield", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {},
        replace: true,
        controller:function($scope,$attrs)  {
            $scope.x=$attrs;

            $scope.$watch('directiveModel',function(){
                $scope.$parent.myModel[$attrs.name]=$scope.directiveModel;
            }) ;

            $scope.directiveModel=$attrs.value;
        },
        template: buildFormTemplate('<input ng-model="directiveModel" id="{{x.id}}" type="text" name="{{x.name}}" value="{{x.value}}" />');

    };
});
```

**[Plunkr Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/IWSWjhJ8CSHjcBwRzEZe?p=preview)**

Comment: Here's another version that uses `ng-repeat` and only attribute required in html is for passing in the object for the element from main controller  http://plnkr.co/edit/kcxFA7lrnlMoScrHYlAC?p=preview

Answer (score 6):

Try a version of this:

```
.directive('myDir', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope:    {
                    YYY: '=ngModel'
                  },
        require:  'ngModel',
        replace:  true,
        template: '<input ng-model="YYY" />'
    };
});
```

Comment: Angular 1.0.8 does not accept a function as template: `Template must have exactly one root element. was: function render(element, attrs) {return '<input ng-model="YYY" />';}`