# AngularJS: How do I access ng-model values injected from custom directive template?

Tags: angularjs, directive, angular-ngmodel

I ran into a problem with AngularJS concerning directives and ng-model.

Assume the following example:

Within my HTML file:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in data">
    <directive-item data="item"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>This is some input: {{ myinput }} </span>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

My app.js looks like this (stripped for readability):

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [
      { value: 'something' }
    ];
}]);

app.directive('directiveItem', function($compile) {
  var template = '<div>'
                + '<label for="myinput">{{ data.value }}</label>'
                + '<input type="text" ng-model="myinput" />'
               + '</div>';

  var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.html(template).show();
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
  };

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: linker,
    scope: {
      data: '='
    }
  };
});
```

Maybe you can see my problem.
Everything works fine, except the display of {{ myinput }} outside of my directive.
It works perfect, if I display it within the injected template, but not outside of it. I did a LOT of google-research, but didn't find anything to help me out.

To clear some things out in front: $scope.data contains multiple objects with different data sets in my real application. So please look at this only as a quick example.
Also I do inject some more templates from my directive depending on a given $scope.data.object.type. The given code is only a rough example of what I have. As mentioned, everything else works without flaws.

Anyone here got an idea?

Regards!

€dit:
@Zeeshan did come up with a good way. Not yet 100% what I am looking for, but it pushes my thinking in another direction.
If anyone has the perfect solution, I am free for ideas! Thanks!

Comment: I tried to fiddle around a bit, but couldn't get it to work. Maybe this answer is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597228/angular-using-ng-model-with-expression-in-directive-template

Comment: @Rias I found that Q before and unfortunately that didn't help me, that's why I started my own Q. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 3):

[Angular Best Practice](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive): Use the scope option to create isolate scopes when making components that you want to reuse throughout your app. I have tried a few cases to build understanding, with object (reference | alias behavior), with plain string. Following snippet simulates:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{ value: 'something' }];
    $scope.bar = {value:'barInitValueAsObject'};
    $scope.tar = 'tarInitValueAsNonObject';
}])
.directive('oneItem', function($compile) {
  return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          foo: '=',
          bar:'=',
          tar:'=',
          },
        template: '<div><label for="bar">{{ foo }} : </label> <input type="text" ng-model="bar.value" /></div>'  
        + '<div><label for="bar">{{ foo }}</label> : <input type="text" ng-model="tar" /></div>'
  }
})
  
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example15-production</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">      
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">        
    <div ng-repeat="item in data">          
      <one-item foo="item.value" bar="bar" tar="tar"></one-item>
    </div>
    <div>
      <br><br>
      <span>This is bar @ Parent : {{ bar.value }} </span>
      <br><br>
      <span>This is tar @ Parent : {{ tar }} </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[Plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/V2DQvL4WaWWVKeGlqAdu?p=preview)

Happy Helping!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's not yet 100% what I need, but you did push my brain in another direction ;-) I will continue to work this out and keep this Q updated! Again, thank you for your solution.

Comment: Can't yet give you a real up, because my reputation is too low (15 required on SO). Will do so as soon as I am able to.
Thank you for trying to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another two-way binding in the directive's isolate scope.  You already are passing in the `data` variable, so just add another variable to the scope that will bind with your `myInput`.  Since this is a two-way binding, updating the value in one way will update the value elsewhere too.  You'll probably just want to let the directive (and its HTML input) handle the input.

```
...  
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: linker,
    scope: {
      data: '=',
      myInput: '='
}
```

Finally, your scopes are not lining up properly because of your ng-repeat.  It's not clear whether you want your display within the ng-repeat or not, so I just put the display also within the ng-repeat.  In your controller's HTML:

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in data">
    <directive-item data="item" my-input="myInput"></directive-item>
    <span>This is some input: {{ myinput }} </span>
  </div>
  <div>

  </div>
```

Check out this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DThoo9I4dKPBXT5Mt3lC?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but unfortunately this does not work. I get an error after implementing your suggestion:
[$compile:nonassign] Expression undefined...

Comment: Thanks again. This does work, but unfortunately that is not what I need. I really do need my `<span>This is some input: {{ myInput }}</span>` outside my ng-repeat. My actual application is very huge and the directive handles a ton of inputs. I need to display some of those inputs within an extra div.

Comment: @Carnivorus Ok.  The only way I can think of to do that is to bind the `myInput` to an element of an array in your controller (or potentially to a property of the `data` object). Then pull the proper element to the display (not sure how you will decide which input is correct).  Best of luck.

Comment: I hope there is another way, else I have to start thinking about some kind of work-around like you are proposing. Thank you anyway.